# Include lib headers in test target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, llvm

I have a project consisting in a library that generates `mylib.a`. This lib needs another custom framework, `MyFW.framework`. In order to develop `mylib` I put the headers of `MyFW.framework` in the directory `$(SRCROOT)/Libs/include/MyFW/`.

In order to work in dev time I added that very same route to the `Header Search Paths` setting of the `mylib` target. This works perfectly when developing, and when using the lib in consumer projects combined with the actual `MyFW.framework`.

The problem is in the test target of `mylib`, when linking it fails with this message in both headers:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyFWHeader1", referenced from:
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyFWHeader2", referenced from:

(same error with x86_64. Cannot test on device, these are logic tests).

I did the same setup in my test target that in the lib target. I did a lot of search about this but I can't find the solution.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This linker issue basically means 1 of 3 things. 1. The library is missing the architecture you’re trying to compile your project for. 2. You didn’t tell the linker to link the library to your target. 3. Your headers have declarations for something that isn’t actually in the library

Comment: Yes, I can read into it but as I wrote the very same setup and lib works for the app target, but not for the test target. Thanks, Allen.